# Emerging/Disappearing correlation in time series (Pearson correlation)

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r

[My first question here. Thanks for taking the time to look into it!]

I am working on public health data where I calculate the correlation between incident counts (zero or positive integers) from two different locations. I calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient r - as I am testing for a linear relationship. Every month, new data points become available. I am looking for an effective tool to identify when two locations start (or stop) to be correlated. I want to answer the following kind of question: Were the incident counts at the two locations correlated in the most recent N months?

Currently, my approach is to take data for the N (N=9) most recent months from two locations and calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient and track how it develops over time. I check whether it is increasing or decreasing and whether it is statistically significant. **Is this approach valid?**

Assuming that this approach is solid, I need to choose the appropriate N: I am concerned to end up with spurious results if I use not enough data points. However, if I use more data points, the information becomes available too late to be useful, in other words, decision makers need to know as soon as possible. With a lower N, the p value for the correlation coefficient increases. It gets harder to get statistically significant results as N decreases. Fair. **Is there anything else that can help me set N appropriately so that I don't miss real correlations as they emerge and don't report spurious correlations?**

Comment: I would suggest plotting the point pairs as a scatterplot and connecting them in temporal order.  While they remain correlated the resulting curve will wander near the diagonal line, but as soon as the correlation changes the curve will depart from that region.  That suggests approaching this as a bivariate *changepoint* problem.  However, the plot might be clearer and more useful than any statistical procedure, especially for giving early warning signals.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I have actually tried this but didn't go particularly deep. I am thinking it might be useful to plot only the recent data pairs and show a trendline of a larger dataset as reference. Thanks for dropping the notion of a "bivariate changepoint problem". Do you have a preferred reference to start exploring this?

Comment: As I recall, the vignette for the [`ecp` package for `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecp/index.html) has a worthwhile discussion.  I tested many of the changepoint packages offered for `R` several years ago and this one rose to the top for my purposes.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check it out!